# OnKeyPressed event not triggered on TableRow in TableView Javafx8

Tags: tableview, javafx-8, fxml, tablerow, onkeypress

I'm trying to have a KeyEvent handler on a TableRow of TableView, but the handler doesn't get called. I'm aware that a handler can be registered on the TableView and use the selectionmodel/ focus model to get the slected or focussed item but i want to register a key event on row for a specific use case. 
The documentation of onKeyPressed event says,

```
Defines a function to be called when this Node or its child Node has input focus and a key has been pressed. The function is called only if the event hasn't been already consumed during its capturing or bubbling phase.
```

The table row doesn't get the event because some other node has already consumed it ?

Is there a way i can make the event triggered on to the tablerow?
Here's the code i'm using

```
    table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
        TableRow<MyObject> row = new TableRow<>();
        row.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(" In the key event");

            }
        });
```

Comment: It looks like the table row cedes ownership of the keyboard focus to the table view as soon as you select it. Since the table row essentially never has keyboard focus, it doesn't receive key events.

Comment: can we somehow capture the event on tablerow , my be by extending the tablerow class and modifying certain part of the code ?  Any sugesstions/ideas that you want me to give a try ?

Comment: Two ideas, neither of which I really like: have each row register a key handler on the table view, and if the row is selected either call `fireEvent` on the table row with that event (probably the event needs to be suitable modified for its target and source, and you need to make sure you don't get into an infinite loop as the fired event may be subsequently handled by the table view). Or, use either listeners or a custom skin on the table to allow the table row to receive focus. (Maybe register listeners with `table.focusedProperty()` and grab focus on the row if it's selected...?).

Comment: I this what you meant , when you said ,'have each row register a key handler on the table view' ?                                        `table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
TableRow<MyObject> tableRow = new TableRow<MyObject>();
tableRow.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<Event>() {@Override
public void handle(Event event) {
System.out.println("in the event handler ");
}
});
tableRow.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<Event>() {
@Override
public void handle(Event event) {
System.out.println("in the event filter" + tableRow.isSelected());
    }
   });`

Comment: No, I meant "on the table *view*". You're registering handlers on the table *row*, which won't get invoked because the row doesn't get focus. Perhaps there is just a better way to solve your use case. Why do you (think you) need to put key handlers on the row, and not on the table?

Comment: i have two instances of the same fxml  (thats has tableView) which use the same controller instance. when there is only one instance of the fxml, using the selectedItem of selectionModel serves my purpose. But  when i open a new stage with the new fxml instance , the latest instance always has the focus . So when i go back to the old fxml instance and do a selection, it always returns the slectedItem of the latest instance.

Comment: "I have two instances of the same FXML which use the same controller instance" - this seems like an incredibly bad idea to start with. You will replace all the injected variables from the first fxml instance with those from the second, so you won't have access to the controls from the first fxml. Use the standard approach and use a different controller instance for each fxml instance. They can share a model instance if they need to communicate data between them.

Comment: its just an idea i was trying , thanks for  this point 'Use the standard approach and use a different controller instance for each fxml instance. They can share a model instance if they need to communicate data between them'

Comment: I think you have proved that this idea doesn't work :).

Answer (score 0):

```
   table.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
              if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
              MyObject rowData = (MyObject)tbl.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println(rowData.getName);

              }
        }
    });
```

Comment: it gives same use as table row button click to get row Data to a variable