# JavaFX TableRow KeyListener doesn't works at all

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I need to add a `KeyListener` on each `TableRow` of the `TableView` , cause when some keys are pressed on the selected `TableRow` i want to get that `Tablerow` Object and pass it somewhere for calculations.

Example code below , demostrating that `KeyListener` is not working for some reason i don't know:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Demostrates an Example of TableRow KeyListener now working
 *
 */
public class TableRowKeyListenerExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
    table.getItems().addAll(createData());

    TableColumn<Item, Item> deleteCol = createTableColumn("Delete", ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Item>::new);
    deleteCol.setCellFactory(this::createDeleteCell);

    table.getColumns().addAll(Arrays.asList(createTableColumn("Name", Item::nameProperty),
        createTableColumn("Value", Item::valueProperty), deleteCol));


    //Custom Row Factory
    table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
        TableRow<Item> row = new TableRow<>();

        //---------------------------------------Key Listener HERE IS NOT WORKING AT ALL FOR SOME REASON---------------------------------------------
        row.setFocusTraversable(true);
        row.setOnKeyReleased(k -> {
        System.out.println("Key Released....");

        });
        row.setOnKeyPressed(k -> {
        System.out.println("Key Released....");

        });

        return row;
    });
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    }

    //----------------------------------IGNORE THE BELOW------------------------------------------------
    private List<Item> createData() {
    Random rng = new Random();
    List<Item> data = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        data.add(new Item("Item " + i, rng.nextInt(10)));
    }
    return data;
    }

    private <S, T> TableColumn<S, T> createTableColumn(String name, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> propertyMapper) {
    TableColumn<S, T> col = new TableColumn<>(name);
    col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> propertyMapper.apply(cellData.getValue()));
    return col;
    }

    private TableCell<Item, Item> createDeleteCell(TableColumn<Item, Item> col) {
    ObservableList<Item> itemList = col.getTableView().getItems();
    TableCell<Item, Item> cell = new TableCell<>();
    cell.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    Button button = new Button("Delete");
    button.setOnAction(event -> itemList.remove(cell.getItem()));
    cell.graphicProperty().bind(Bindings.when(cell.emptyProperty()).then((Node) null).otherwise(button));
    return cell;
    }

    /**
     * Item for the TableView
     *
     */
    public static class Item {
    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
    private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "value");

    public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public final java.lang.String getName() {
        return this.nameProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setName(final java.lang.String name) {
        this.nameProperty().set(name);
    }

    public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public final int getValue() {
        return this.valueProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setValue(final int value) {
        this.valueProperty().set(value);
    }

    public Item(String name, int value) {
        setName(name);
        setValue(value);
    }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

After the comment of `Loris Securo` i have added this:

I want when a key is released on the TableView (for example K) to get the selected `TableRow`.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452735/onkeypressed-event-not-triggered-on-tablerow-in-tableview-javafx8

Comment: @Loris Securo I have readed all the comments of the link you posted and decided to change a little bit the question . I have added two lines at the end :) .

Comment: do you really need to get a `TableRow`? Would it be ok to get the selected `Item` instead?

Comment: @Loris Securo  Yes i want to show a ContextMenu based on TableRow position on the Screen . So i am getting the selected TableRow to calculate it's bounds and position in screen . Do you know other way :) ?